# Using Statsmodel ARIMA without dates

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I have a time series but I do not have any Dates.

I know that the collected data is evenly spaced.

Statsmodel ARIMA assumes that I must have dates and throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates
```

Is it not possible to utilize ARIMA without knowing the dates?

Comment: If you know that they are evenly spaced and you need dates - why not create dummy dates and space them evenly? every day or so? beside that: Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have attempted to do so but I am unfamiliar with Pandas and Numpy, if you could provide a code excerpt it would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you post the code that produces the error alongside the error by editing your question so it is easier for us to  copy&paste it into an IDE and fix it. Post sample data as well. Thanks. If you have no clue at all, SO is the wrong place to ask, tutorials teach you the basics, f.e. start here: [arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/)

Comment: I meant to say that I am unfamiliar with Pandas and how I would go about to create the dummy dates and set they as the key for the dataframe. As I had attempted it yesterday and today and was not successful I decided to post the question on SO.

Comment: simpler way is to just use a numpy array instead of pandas Series, numpy arrays don't have an index. The main advantage of using dates is that predict and forecast periods can be specified by dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My data consists of a single .csv file as follows:

```
286
276
...
239
236
```

In order to use the "statsmodels.tsa.arima_model" package for whatever reason still not clear to me (since ARIMA should be able to operate without specified dates as far as I understand) your DataFrame index must be in pandas.DatetimeIndex format.

I have created dummy dates with a day of frequency as follows:

```
my_data = pd.read_csv('data_2018.csv', header=None)
my_data = my_data.values.flatten()

# create dummy dates for the arima modules....
dates = pd.date_range('1900-1-1', periods=len(my_data), freq='D')
# add the dates and the data to a new dataframe
ts = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'data': my_data})
# set the dataframe index to be the dates column
ts = ts.set_index('dates')
```

Comment: I was moving this into your question - but did this answer your question it should be left as answer so removed my edit again. Did this solve your problem?

Comment: It did, "You can accept your own answer in 2 days.". No choice but to wait.

Comment: Sorry for botching your questions edit history then :)

Comment: followed this procedure but getting Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data) error.